# How to disable only previous week in Jquery datetimepicker?

Tags: datetimepicker

How can I disable **only previous week** in Jquery datetimepicker? All the dates before previous week should be **enabled**.Please see my code

```
if($('.datetimepicker').length > 0 ){
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({   
        minDate: d,     
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'    
   
    });
```

where the value of d I am passing through some function.